# text file carriage return not displaying with PHP_EOL

Tags: php, text

I am using PHP_EOL to add a new line to text files in PHP. I understand the difference between line feed and a carriage return, However when I export the text file and view it through a hex editor instead of seeing 0D0A(carriage return, line feed) I only see 0A (which is line feed) at the end of each line.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem but the upstream program needs to see 0D0A at the end of each line.

I am stuck on this and would appreciate some help.

I have also tried "\r\n" but that produces something worse. instead of 0D0A it produces is 0A0A or \n\n!

Other thing to note is that this is being hosted on a linux system and downloaded with windows(don't know if it matters what OS downloads it or not)

Thanks

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is interpreted in the machine environment that executes the script. So if you execute it on a Linux box, then it will always output `\n` and likewise if you ran that same php script on a Windows server, then it would output whatever mangled line ending Microsoft sees fit to use in their infinite wisdom.

Comment: Thanks Jeff that make sense. So by that logic I should be using "\r\n" right. But that results in double line feed... the strangest part in all of this is that this exact script was running fine but until a week ago.

Comment: I don't know, that's strange. Try `echo chr(0x0D);` and see if that at least spits out the literal character. Since it's something that changed recently, inspect your change log. Should be easy to pinpoint if you're using version control by doing a binary search checking out commits since the last working code.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on system that hosts your script, \n and \r have the equivalent meant, but on very outdated server PHP_EOL can be undefined, I always use this bit code to preserve my PHP_EOL:

```
<?php
  if (!defined('PHP_EOL')) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'WIN')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\r\n");
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'MAC')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\r");
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'DAR')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
    } else {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
    }
  }
?>
```

So you can use PHP_EOL without problems... PHP_EOL means \n or \r or \r\n...

Note: PHP_EOL can be

```
1) on Unix    LN    == \n
2) on Mac     CR    == \r
3) on Windows CR+LN == \r\n
4) on Darwin  LN    == \n
```

Darwin is MacOS X that is similar to Unix and has the same end of line...

Hope this help.